# Find a center point of multiple lat lng

Tags: iphone, objective-c, center, latitude-longitude

I have multiple lat lng and I want the center point of all this lat lng.. like the meeting point which will be closest to all this lat lng.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine the centroid of multiple points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353684/determine-the-centroid-of-multiple-points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculated the mean position of that coords:

```
float lat=0, lng=0;
for(int i=0; i<num_coords; ++i) {
   lat += lats[i];
   lng += lngs[i];
}

lat /= num_coords;
lng /= num_coords;
```

When the distance between locations is less than 500 miles (800 km), this method gives a close approximation to the true geographic midpoint.

Comment: This is wrong. Longitudes -179 degrees and +179 degrees are very close. Your answer will give 0, which is halfway around the world!

Comment: This answer gives the average which is incorrect for question.

Comment: I did an edit to your answer.  When the edit if accepted I will take back my downvote.

Comment: wrong answer. Like @BlackFrog said this gives the average! Take a look at Centroids on wikipedia

Answer (score 6):

Actually, there are two different points. Look [here](http://www.geomidpoint.com/methods.html).

- **Center of gravity**

The geographic midpoint, sometimes called the center of gravity, center of mass or centroid is the average coordinate for a set of points. If you mark several points on a world globe along with the geographic midpoint, the geographic midpoint does indeed look like it is in the center. Imagine that several weights are placed at various points on a world globe and then the globe is allowed to rotate freely until the heaviest part of the globe is pulled by gravity until it is facing downward. Then the lowest point on the globe would be the geographic midpoint for all of the weighted locations.

The geographic midpoint is calculated by finding the center of gravity for the locations. The latitude and longitude for the locations are converted into Cartesian (x,y,z) coordinates. The average x, y and z coordinate is calculated. This average coordinate lies within the interior of the earth and is the true center of mass, and a line can be drawn from the center of the earth passing through this point then out to the surface of the earth which is the geographic midpoint. The average x, y and z coordinate is converted into the latitude and longitude for the midpoint.

The given formula assumes a spherical earth, and sea-level points. The answer is much more complex if a more accurate model is needed.

- **Center of minimum distance**

This point minimizes the combined travel distance from a set of points. The center of minimum distance is the point of absolute minimum travel distance, however it does not attempt to equalize the amount of distance traveled from the other points.

There are calculators [here](http://www.geomidpoint.com/)

The methods are described [here](http://www.geomidpoint.com/calculation.html)

Note that sperical earth is assumed. If higher accuracy is needed, the solution would be much more complex.

Comment: Agree, that simple average method is not the best for cases, when you need to calculate coords that may vary a lot, however for the simple iPhone app it won't really matter cause the distance is too small (and as for the -179 and 179 - this is Pacific ocean almost everywhere there).