# find the nearest point

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a lot of points. I would like to find an algorithm which can create a new point that has the closet position to all points. Can you help me ?
For example if I enter the following points:
[image: input]

I will get this point:

[image]

PS: I have already a function distance(point1,point2). This function calculates the distance between 2 points

PS: My point are coordinates in lon/lat

Comment: `•a specific programming problem
•a software algorithm
•software tools commonly used by programmers
•practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession` - I don't think you fall into any [of these...](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [Centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_finite_set_of_points)

[image]

Assuming X<sub>i</sub> is a point (or in the general case an n-dimensional vector).

Comment: why is it the "nearest" point?

Comment: The proof is referenced in the link he attached.

Comment: @irreputable You're right technically this is only the "closest" point if you consider "closest" to be minimizing the sum of squared distances between the point and all other points. The OP might have other criteria for "closest", but I think that is a safe assumption to make given that they didn't specify any abnormal conditions for "closeness".

Comment: there can be many engineering examples where the sum of distance, not squared, is important.

Comment: @irreputable "There can be many" -certainly there *can* be many, but the *normal* way to describe a "closest" point is to minimize the sum of squared distances.

Comment: I didn't specified it. My points are different locations in lon/lat.
I found the solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353684/determine-the-centroid-of-multiple-points

Answer (score 3):

Sum up all x and y coordinate values and divide by number of points:

Asume you have 3 points:

```
  x =   (x1 + x2 + x3) / 3;

  y=    (y1 + y2 + y3) / 3;
```